# JSF actionListener gets called although validationFailed from ace:textAreaEntry validator

Tags: validation, jsf-2, icefaces-3

I am using ICEfaces 3.2. I have a validator method defined for a particular `ace:textAreaEntry` field. If the validation code inside my validator fails I am adding a faces error message to the context. I expected that when this error message gets added to the context, my `actionListener` would not get executed. But what I notice is that even after adding faces error message to the context from my validator, the `actionListener` gets executed. I thought that because the validation failed, faces won't execute the `actionlistener`.

XHTML textareaentry code:

```
<ace:textAreaEntry
  id="addrincountryofincorp"
  value="#{strformbean.addrInCountryOfIncorp}"
  required="true" styleClass="#{facesContext.validationFailed?'ui-state-error':''}"
  label="Address in Country of Incorporation" cols="50" rows="5"
  validator="#{strformbean.validateAddrLen}" />
```

Validator method:

```
public void validateAddrLen(FacesContext fc,UIComponent uc, Object obj){
  int len = 0;
  Map compAttr = uc.getAttributes();
  log.debug("inside validateAddrLen...");
  log.debug("obj = "+obj);
  if(obj !=  null && ! obj.equals("")){
    len = obj.toString().length();
    if(len > 200){
      Utility.addValMesgToContext(compAttr.get("label").toString() + " cannot exceed 200 Characters");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is considered failed only if you actually throw a `javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException`

Try throwing an Exception with the FacesMessage inside:

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("my validaton message");
msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
throw new ValidatorException(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks ,i was not aware that i should throw a validatorexception.